# Can't figure out phpstorm terminal keymap for arrow keys in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, command-line, shortcut-keys, ide, intellij

I want to load my previous commands or move cruser back and forward in what I'm writing in phpstorm terminal while using `php artisan tinker` a playground for checking our code to see if it works, but when I'm pressing arrow keys I get : `^[[A^[[B^[[B`, I've tried to search through the key map but I couldn't figure out how to fix this. 
FYI : I don't have this problem on mac or windows.

another question I have if i change my phpstorm keymap to mac, whats Metta key in keyboard ?!

Comment: That means `phpstorm` terminal does not have `readline(3)` support.

Comment: It has in mac and windows my problem is linux !

Comment: Check the compilation options, `readline(3)` support might be needed to be specified at compilation time.

Comment: @heemayl I've searched it's keymap for readline or compile or compilation but there is nothing for it.

Comment: I've figured this problem happens when I bring up php artisan tinker - in php artisan tinker I can't use arrow keys in linux why is that ?